# multiple count and sum MySQL function returning wrong values with multiple joins in MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

***Table mpkids_students AS A***

```
id      BranchId    Email                   Mobile      StudentId
9497    25          mpsuraj2016@gmail.com   8700698773  25
9498    25          m016@gmail.com          8700698776  26
```

***Table mpkids_student_image_gallery AS B***

```
id      like_count  student_id
1       25          27
```

***Table mpkids_visitors AS C***

```
id      student_id
1       9497
2       9497
3       9497
```

***Table mpkids_visitors_count AS D***

```
id  visitor_count   student_id
1   4               23
```

***Table mpkids_image_likes AS E***

```
id  student_id
1   67
```

***Table mpkids_relatives_data AS F***

```
id  student_id  rel_email               rel_mobile
1   9497        kushwahji@gmail.com     9009859691
2   9497        kushwah@gmail.com       7566403326
3   9497        kushwah@gmail.com       1236403326
4   9497        suraj@gmail.com         123640332
```

***Table mpkids_paidstatus AS G***

```
id  student_id  Received
1   9497        7500
2   9497        3000
3   9497        3000
```

***MYSQL QUERY***

```
SELECT A.id as student_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) as images, 
COUNT(DISTINCT C.id)+ COUNT(DISTINCT D.visitor_count)  as visits, 
count(DISTINCT E.id) + SUM(B.like_count) as likes, 
COUNT(DISTINCT A.Email)+COUNT(DISTINCT F.rel_email)  as emails, 
COUNT(DISTINCT A.Mobile)+COUNT(DISTINCT F.rel_mobile)  as moibles, 
SUM(G.Received)  as Received 
FROM mpkids_students AS A 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_student_image_gallery AS B ON B.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_visitors AS C ON C.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_visitors_count AS D ON D.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_image_likes AS E ON E.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_relatives_data AS F ON F.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_paidstatus AS G ON G.student_id = A.id 
WHERE A.BranchId = 25 
GROUP BY A.id 
ORDER BY A.StudentId DESC
```

***Result:***

```
student_id  images  visits  likes   emails  moibles Received    
9497        0       3       NULL    4       5       202500  
9498        0       0       NULL    1       1       NULL
```

***Problem  Explanation:***

Received Field returning wrong value i have tried many queries but not getting solution 
Received Field correct value 13500 for student_id = 9497
Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting wrong output because, when you are joining based on studentid, you are getting multiple records from `mpkids_paidstatus` table for each student, which is adding up and returning a wrong output.

You can also write your query like following using subquery.

```
SELECT A.id as student_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) as images, 
COUNT(DISTINCT C.id)+ COUNT(DISTINCT D.visitor_count)  as visits, 
count(DISTINCT E.id) + SUM(B.like_count) as likes, 
COUNT(DISTINCT A.Email)+COUNT(DISTINCT F.rel_email)  as emails, 
COUNT(DISTINCT A.Mobile)+COUNT(DISTINCT F.rel_mobile)  as moibles, 
(select SUM(Received) from mpkids_paidstatus ps where ps.student_id=a.id)  as Received 
FROM mpkids_students AS A 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_student_image_gallery AS B ON B.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_visitors AS C ON C.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_visitors_count AS D ON D.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_image_likes AS E ON E.student_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN mpkids_relatives_data AS F ON F.student_id = A.id 

WHERE A.BranchId = 25 
GROUP BY A.id 
ORDER BY A.StudentId DESC
```